# What is the difference between these two types of training?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, supervised-learning, computer-vision, pattern-recognition

Suppose that I want to detect if a picture contains a particular logo, for instance the following one.

[image]

Since template matching would be slow and fail those scaled or resized ones, I decided to train a classifier and I have two ideas:

1. Gather many pictures that contain the logo and many others that don't, and directly train a binary classification model.
2. After gathering the training data in the first step, I combine the logo and every image in the two types of images. For example, I combine(using this [online tool](https://www.imgonline.com.ua/eng/combine-two-images-into-one.php)) the logo with an image not containing the logo as follows:

[image]

and keep the labels.

I think they are two types of learning: In the first approach, the model pushes the embeddings/representations of the two kinds of pictures away in the space and hence if I try a different logo, the model would become dull; while in the second approach the model would learn to find the trick: If there exists a pattern somewhere in the picture which has the same shape/pattern as the left part of the picture(where the logo lies), the label should be one.

I wonder if the difference is transductive learning vs inductive learning? If not, what is it?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I answered a similar question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/570268/103153