# Multivariate time series forecasting and LSTM: When should I separate time series in different inputs

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, lstm

Let us suppose that I have a multivariate time series with two variables that vary together in time: var1 and var 2. And let us suppose that I want to forecast the n-ith value of var 2, by considering a window with the n-1 past values of var1 and var2.

I would like to use a LSTM in the first layer.

I'm not sure if it would be better to consider a single input with 2 dimensions (providing the n-1 values of both variables) or if it would be better to separate both variables in two different inputs (two separate LSTM whose values can be concatenated later).

Is there any rule or heuristic for guiding this decision?

Best regards.

Comment: Your question may be a duplicate of mine: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/568131/103153

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the early fusion, mid fusion, or late fusion in this paper: [Multimodal Bottleneck Transformer (MBT): A New Model for Modality Fusion](https://ai.googleblog.com/2022/03/multimodal-bottleneck-transformer-mbt.html). Multimodal features are just more dissimilar features, and sometimes you can change one modal into another. For instance, you can change (predefined) events into words.

[image]

If your features are put as a whole into the neural network earlier(the inputs can be treated as the first hidden/fusion layer), feature fusion would happen earlier, otherwise later.

Late fusion has its benefits: restricting feature connections to later layers, allowing earlier layers to specialize in learning unifeature features; and you can also benefit from early fusion because if your input features share lots of similar sub-features, they can connect earlier. It depends on the features of your features/inputs.

In your specific scenario, it would be better to decide if the two features matter in time order. If so, it would be better to encode the time order in some form, either in early fusion or late fusion layer.